# How to disable multi clicks in the c# application programming?

Tags: c#

In the c sharp application program, if a button is clicked then a dialog box will be opened but if the user clicked more than one time then more dialog boxes are opened. How to overcome it? 
Please give me the solution regarding this issue.

Answer (score 3):

If its a desktop application use Modal Dialogs.

Comment: +1 since this is the "built-in, directly supported" way to accomplish what he's looking for.

Answer (score 2):

use ShowDialog function:

```
using (Form2 frm = new Form2())
{
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

This will disable the current form and only make the new form usable.

Alternatively, you can disable the button to prevent it from being clicked again.

```
button1.Enabled = false;
```

But make sure you enable the button when it should be accessible again.

Comment: +1.  This was posted while I was making my answer.  I like the idea of disabling the button better than using a private variable.  Binding to the Close event on the sub-dialog might be a good way to figure out when to re-enable the button, so you could try combining my answer and Fun's.

Answer (score 2):

Furquan has a good answer.  **Edit**: as does Fun.

If you can't or don't want your dialog to be modal, you can add extra state to see if the subdialog is already open.  Here's some example pseudo-code (it probably won't compile):

```
class MyForm : Form
{
  public void OnButtonClick()
  {
    if(!isSubDialogOpen)
    {
      isSubDialogOpen = true;
      ShowSubDialog();
    }
  }

  private void OnSubDialogClose()
  {
    isSubDialogOpen = false;
  }

  private void ShowSubDialog()
  {
    SubDialog subDialog = new SubDialog(this);
    subDialog.OnClose += OnSubDialogClose;
    subDialog.Show();
  }

  private bool isSubDialogOpen;
}

class SubDialog : Form
{
  // ...
}
```